# Why is output different if function definition is after main in Python?

Tags: python

The output of below code is different if:

```
def foo():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except Exception:
        return  'Caught in foo'

try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except Exception:
    print 'Caught in main'
```

OUTPUT : FOOO \n Caught in foo

```
try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except Exception:
    print 'Caught in main'


def foo():
    try:
        print 1/0
    except Exception:
        return  'Caught in foo'
```

OUTPUT : FOOO \n Caught in main

Why is the output different in both cases?

Comment: The answers show you why it is always best to only catch specific exceptions, like `ZeroDivisionError` in your case, and not all exceptions,as it makes finding problems very hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they raise different exceptions.

[*All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from `Exception`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy). `except Exception` catches most of the exceptions and this behaviour is often confusing.

You should *always* catch specific exceptions e.g. `1/0` raises [`ZeroDivisionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError) and you should only catch that:

```
try:
    print 'FOOO'
    print foo()
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print 'Caught in foo'
```

You'll see different error in the output

```
FOOO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<file>", line 3, in <module>
    print (foo())
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Because it was not caught by `except ZeroDivisionError` (`issubclass(NameError, ZeroDivisionError)` is `False`).

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second case the exception is:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Try *not* catching the exception in main, or `print` it. `foo` isn't defined by the time you try to call it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you get the following error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

In the second case however you get:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

The second one occurs because the `foo()` function is not defined yet when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the second case, foo is not defined yet and thus calling foo() throws an exception.